# Выбор option из select

Tags: php, html

```
          <div class="form-group">
                <label for="body">Должность</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="group">
                @foreach($branches as $branch)
                  <option value="{{ $branch->id }}">{{ $branch->name }}</option>
                @endforeach 
              </select>
          </div>
```

Сейчас при загрузки страницы в option выводится первая запись из базы, как мне сделать чтоб первая опция была по дефолту не из базы, а например должность Директор ?

Comment: Вне цикла добавьте новую  опцию и впишите должность директора

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавь: `<option value="Директор" selected="true">Директор</option>`

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="body">Должность</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="group">
            <option value="Директор" selected="true">Директор</option>
            @foreach($branches as $branch)
              <option value="{{ $branch->id }}">{{ $branch->name }}</option>
            @endforeach 
          </select>
      </div>
```